# Div positioning while printing multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html

Good Afternoon,

So I have a page that has circle.png images being moved around using JS to circle certain fixed spots I have designated. Here is the code:

```
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>
<!--
function move_img(str) {

switch(str){
case "ss":
document.getElementById('dwr_style').style.left=118 + "px";
document.getElementById('dwr_style2').style.left=118 + "px";
document.getElementById('dwr_style2').style.top=1410 + "px";
break;

case "rout":
document.getElementById('dwr_style').style.left=180 + "px";
document.getElementById('dwr_style2').style.left=180 + "px";
document.getElementById('dwr_style2').style.top=1410 + "px";
break;

case "fp":
document.getElementById('dwr_style').style.left=240 + "px";
document.getElementById('dwr_style2').style.left=240 + "px";
document.getElementById('dwr_style2').style.top=1410 + "px";
break;

case "dt_std":
document.getElementById('dt').style.left=390 + "px";
document.getElementById('dt2').style.left=390 + "px";
document.getElementById('dt2').style.top=1678 + "px";
document.getElementById('dt').style.width=70 + "px";
document.getElementById('dt2').style.width=70 + "px";
break;

case "dt_34":
document.getElementById('dt').style.left=465 + "px";
document.getElementById('dt').style.width=40 + "px";
document.getElementById('dt2').style.left=465 + "px";
document.getElementById('dt2').style.width=40 + "px";
document.getElementById('dt2').style.top=1678 + "px";
break;

case "dt_1":
document.getElementById('dt').style.left=505 + "px";
document.getElementById('dt').style.width=40 + "px";
document.getElementById('dt2').style.left=505 + "px";
document.getElementById('dt2').style.width=40 + "px";
document.getElementById('dt2').style.top=1678 + "px";
break;
}
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>

<img src="CalDoor.jpg">
<div style="position:absolute;top:30;left:590;">1</div>
<input type=text style="position:absolute;border:none;top:185;left:100;" placeholder="Enter Job Name">
<?php

$file = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
$file2 = nl2br(file_get_contents($file));
$file3 = str_replace('"' , '' , $file2);
$file4 = str_replace('ÿþ' , '' , $file3);
$line_break = explode("<br />" , $file4);
$topchange=105;
$count = 0;
foreach ($line_break as $final1) {

    $final2 = explode(";" , $final1);
        $regex = '#\((([^()]+|(?R))*)\)#';
        preg_match($regex, $final1, $match);

            $type = "S";
            if ($final2[4] == "DF") {
              $type = "DF";
            }
            if ($final2[6] == "Glass") {
                $type = "GL";
            }
            if ($count == 24) {
                $topchange = 1097;
                $pagecount = 2;
                echo '<img src="CalDoor.jpg" style="position:absolute;top:1000;left:8;">';
                echo '<div style="position:absolute;top:1022;left:590;">2</div>';
                echo '<div style="position:absolute;top:1022;left:640;">'. $pagecount .'</div>';
                echo "<img src='circle.png' id='fds' style='position:absolute;Top:1297;Left:20;' width=80 height=25>";
                echo "<img src='circle.png' id='dwr_style2' style='position:absolute;Top:1410;Left:118;' width=70 height=30>";
                echo "<img src='circle.png' id='dt2' style='position:absolute;Top:1678;Left:392;' width=70 height=30>";

            }


         echo "<div style='position:absolute;TOP:". $topchange .";LEFT:395;'>". $final2[1] ."</div>";
         echo "<div style='position:absolute;TOP:". $topchange .";LEFT:450;'>". $final2[3] ."</div>";
         echo "<div style='position:absolute;TOP:". $topchange .";LEFT:365;'>". $match[0] ."</div>";
         echo "<div style='position:absolute;TOP:". $topchange .";LEFT:335;'>". $type ."</div>";
         echo "<div style='position:absolute;TOP:". $topchange .";LEFT:532;'>". $final2[6] ."</div>";
            $changeamt = 24.2;
            $topchange = $topchange + $changeamt;
            $count++;



}
echo '<div style="position:absolute;top:30;left:640;">'; 
echo $pagecount; 
echo '</div>';

?>
<img src='circle.png' id='fds' style='position:absolute;Top:305;Left:20;' width=80 height=25>
<img src='circle.png' id='dwr_style' style='position:absolute;Top:420;Left:118;' width=70 height=30>
<img src='circle.png' id='dt' style='position:absolute;Top:685;Left:392;' width=70 height=30>
<div class='no-print' style='position:absolute;TOP:50;LEFT:900;'>
<b>Drawer Type: </b><br>
<input type=button onClick=move_img('ss') value='Solid Stock'>
<br>
<input type=button onClick=move_img('rout') value='Routed'>
<br>
<input type=button onClick=move_img('fp') value='Five Piece'>
<br><br>
</div>

<div class='no-print' style='position:absolute;TOP:158;LEFT:900;'>
<b>Door Thickness: </b><br>
<input type=button onClick=move_img('dt_std') value='Std 13/16"'>
<br>
<input type=button onClick=move_img('dt_34') value='3/4"'>
<br>
<input type=button onClick=move_img('dt_1') value='1"'>
<br><br>
</div>
```

These circles are absolute because I am projecting them over my CalDoor image. When my file comes over and has over 24 lines of data, I have it project a second CalDoor image below, and the corresponding circles get added to match the upper. The only problem, is when I go to print, it shows the CalDoor images on 2 seperate pages like I want, the circles on the 2nd page retain their horizontal placement, but not their vertical. Any reason?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a jsbin or jsfiddle that shows the issue? Your example code has no CSS at all, so it's difficult to answer your question.

Comment: All the CSS is within the code really. Theres not much more to the code than that.

Comment: And the JSFiddle wont help much because the problem is from printing the page. I dont believe you can print the result section of jsfiddle.

Comment: The point is that you code starts with a `script` tag in the `head` and ends without closing the `body` or `html` tags.  You include php includes in the middle of your body that do stuff, but I'm not going to run the php code through my head and try to figure out what the final html is going to look like.  I don't know what comes before or after the code you posted, and it could make a difference.  It also matters what browser you are using. Do you get the same result with IE7/8/9/10/edge, Firefox, Chrome, Safari?

Comment: If you don't want to make a fiddle, or you think it would be useless, throw up a sample page on your own server to help us debug.

Comment: [Actual Page Display](http://www.gbcab.com/actual.jpg)  
[Print Page Display](http://www.gbcab.com/print.jpg)  
I cant seem to seperate those two links but that is what I am dealing with. My actual page is displaying everything formatted nicely, but when I click to print, the formatting does not hold up. Note: this is for the second page on my print. My first page stays formatted fine.

Comment: Hmm, It seems to be a problem with Firefox's print scaling.. Is there any way to designate print pages with code then?

Comment: Printing CSS still has a long way to go for native browser/javascript solutions.  Since you are using PHP, could you look into a PHP-based PDF generator to do what you need it to do? You could display the PDF in the browser, and printing would give you exactly what you see in the PDF.